# app_glue android NDK : GetMethodID Fails with TextView.setText call

Tags: java, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm working on a native android project with NDK. My code is only C and I need to call some java function via JNI.

I tried and I am able to call some method from the class such as `android`, `view`, `WindowManage`. But when I try to use the `TextView.setText` I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception.

Here is the code :

```
 JNIEnv* jni;
 state->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&jni, NULL);


 jclass activityClassMine = jni->FindClass("android/widget/TextView");
 if(!(activityClassMine))
 LOGI("can't find TextView class...");

 jmethodID SetTextColour = jni->GetMethodID
                              ( activityClassMine
                              , "setTextColor"
                              , "(I)V");        //this works !!!!
 if(!(SetTextColour))
LOGI("textColour Failed...");

 jmethodID getSetText = jni->GetMethodID
                              ( activityClassMine
                              , "setText"
                              , "(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V");

 if(!(getSetText))      //failed                               
 LOGI("setText Failed");
```

I have checked the signature of the method and that is ok, I've tried other available signature for this method but no success ...

Comment: It all looks legitimate. Is the method supported on you Android version? Is there any more code in the middle of the snippet you erased to avoid clutter?

Comment: Did u solve the issue? Kindly post it if you are through